# Get Data from parsed XML to JSON

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get some data from a parsed `XML` to `JSON` but now I'm stuck and not be able to get the data. Could someone show me how to get the data in the right way to show on my screen?

Formatted **JSON Data**

```
{ 
   "event":[ 
      { 
         "name":"Queen",
         "date":"2019-09-12",
         "genre":"rock",
         "time":"20:00:00",
      },
      { 
         "name":"2Pac",
         "date":"2019-09-25",
         "genre":"rap",
         "time":"20:00:00"
      },
data () {
    return {
      result: null
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getConcertData()
  },
  methods: {
    getConcertData () {
      const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString
      this.$axios.get('members.php?xml')
        .then((response) => {
          const self = this
          parseString(response.data, function (err, result) {
            self.events = result
            console.log(result)
          })
        })
    }
  }
```

Comment: What data do you want to retrieve? FYI, you can avoid creating a `self` variable if you use an arrow function, eg `parseString(response.data, (err, result) => { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to confirm if you have successfully obtained the expected format data(use developer tools or just log the response.data),
then make sure require('xml2js').parseString work well.